# AngularJS Directives - unit tests Karma coverage

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I have a problem covering directives unit tests. I used the way from : 
http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2013/12/05/unit-testing-angularjs-directive/ (by Julien Bouquillon)
to create unit tests for my directives. The idea presented on that blog looked great for my needs and well explained, but my issue is that the coverage is not reflected in Karma Coverage(Istanbul code coverage tool).

How should I create my directive unit tests in order to be reflected in coverage summary? Has someone an example that make it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered some issues in my Grunt config file and that's why the coverage wasn't updated. So, the example by Julien Bouquillon is very good and I recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of why you don't see the coverage on the directive code is that, the link you mentioned has used the $compile() and the $digest() called in the beforeEach() through compileDirective() function.

Have that piece of code moved ( the ones that goes into the compileDirective ) into your `it()` , it should have the coverage done on directive.

Instead of

```
describe("do some directive testing",function(){
 beforeEach(function(){
compileDirective();
});
 it('your test code',function(){
    //some code here 
});
```

Do the following.

```
 describe("do some directive testing",function(){
     beforeEach(function(){
       // some other code which execute before each of the it()..
    });
     it('your test code',function(){
        compileDirective();
        //some code here 
    });
```

So essentially you may have to do some adjustment to your code.